# Changing position from absolute to sticky moves `:after` element to bottom of container

Tags: html, css, sticky, pseudo-class

A bit of info on this code first. This is 'legacy code' from education software and there are 1000's of pages marked up like this. So ideally I want to find a solution without changing the markup on every page - if possible!

The problem I have is, there are two images that are fixed to the left and right of the content. This works fine. However now the images need to remain in a sticky position as the user scrolls down the page.

Because the `:before` and `:after` classes are used. As soon as I change to Sticky. The `:after` element is positioned below the container. I know why this happens but wondering if anyone can think of a workaround?

I have tried floating left/right with negative margins, which works for `:before` but not the `:after` element.

I've added the code to this post but the CodePen might also be helpful to view in a wider window as the left/right elements are hidden on narrower viewports. The layout here is correct. The items just need to remain sticky in the same position on scroll.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/ExQvWWg

This is still used for education software, so I'm a bit wary of changing to `flex` as I don't have any data on browsers used. Only other solutions I've thought is applying as background images to the `.container`.

```css
body {
  background: #29cebe url(../img/interface/body-bg.png) center top;
  background-size: 500px 500px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 32%),
    inset 0 -1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 32%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #282c2e;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: calc(100% - 144px);
  letter-spacing: 0.024em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 72px;
  width: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.page-head,
.page-foot {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 72px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.page-foot {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.container:before {
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 370px;
  top: 64px;
  left: -120px;
  width: 111px;
}

.container:after {
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 362px;
  top: 64px;
  right: -112px;
  width: 98px;
}

.wrap {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset -4px -4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%), 4px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 32px 32px 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <header class="page-head">
    Header
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

  <footer class="page-foot">
    Footer
  </footer>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i can do that using JavaScript not sure about css.
here a demo if you want .
it's bit janky sometime but with some tweak you cant convert it to elastic effect.

```js
var containerOverrindeStyle = document.createElement("style");
window.onscroll = function (e) {
 fromTop(Math.ceil(scrollY));
};

function fromTop(offset){

containerOverrindeStyle.innerHTML = `.container:after,.container:before { top: ${
  64 + offset
}px; }`;
document.head.appendChild(containerOverrindeStyle);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #29cebe url(../img/interface/body-bg.png) center top;
  background-size: 500px 500px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 32%),
    inset 0 -1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 32%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #282c2e;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: calc(100% - 144px);
  letter-spacing: 0.024em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 72px;
  width: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.page-head,
.page-foot {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 72px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.page-foot {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.container:before {
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 370px;
  top: 64px;
  left: -120px;
  width: 111px;
}

.container:after {
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 362px;
  top: 64px;
  right: -112px;
  width: 98px;
}

.wrap {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset -4px -4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%), 4px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 32px 32px 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <header class="page-head">
    Header
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

  <footer class="page-foot">
    Footer
  </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go. CSS would be preferred but I just can't see it being done without redoing all the markup!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do that using css :
*open in full page*

```css
body {
  background: #29cebe url(../img/interface/body-bg.png) center top;
  background-size: 500px 500px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 32%),
    inset 0 -1px 0 rgb(255 255 255 / 32%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #282c2e;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: calc(100% - 144px);
  letter-spacing: 0.024em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 72px;
  width: 100%;
}

.page {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-width: 800px;
}

.page-head,
.page-foot {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 72px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

.page-foot {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 32px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1024px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
}

.container:before {
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 370px;
    top: 175px;
    left: -65px;
  width: 111px;
}

.container:after {
  background: red;
  background-size: 100%;
  height: 362px;
     top: 175px;
    right: -35px;
  width: 98px;
}

.wrap {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: inset -4px -4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 8%), 4px 4px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 32px 32px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <header class="page-head">
    Header
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

  <footer class="page-foot">
    Footer
  </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again ...I tried this but I think the client wants the elements to hug the content area more closely than to the left/right of the viewport!

Comment: we can do that too using javascript, set offset by calculating divs width.